# Dynamically adding extra panes into jquery accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hi I have a jquery accordion hard coded in and working perfectly but I would like to dynamically add another pane to the end of the same accordion but I just can't seem to get it.

This is the code im using to try append to the end of the accordion div:

```
$('#accordion').append($('<h3><a href="#"></a>Test</h3><div><table><tr>Hello</tr></table></div>'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Unforunately, it looks like there's no built in way to do this.  But this works:

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion();
$('#add').click(function(){
    $('#accordion').append('<h3><a href="#">Section 5</a></h3><div><p>5</p></div>');
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion('destroy').accordion();
});
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/Vr55M/

Comment: Thats a weird fix but ye it works thanks but doesn't take the same styling as my previous ones.